# Cannot GET /test.html - node.js - javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to learn Angular.js and I'm trying to setup my development environment (as described in Pro Angularjs) and I'm having problems.  Others have experienced similar problems but even after looking at some of the solutions I still can't get mine to work.  Since I'm new to all this it's probably something very basic and your help is appreciated.

My setup is:

In my "nodejs" directory I have a directory called "angularjs" and a file called "server.js" whose contents are shown below:

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var app = connect();

app.use(serveStatic("/angularjs"));
app.listen(5000);
```

In my "angularjs" folder I have a file called "test.html" with contents:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>First Test</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn btn-default">{{"AngularJS"}}</div>
    <div class="btn btn-success">Bootstrap</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it I get "Cannot GET /test.html".  Any help is appeciated.

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: Try renaming it to 'index.html' instead of 'test.html'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
app.use(serveStatic("./angularjs"));
```

Comment: Thanks yzarubin.  I actually thought I tried that but apparently not.  Everything is working now.